# Is it possible to get multiple routes available between 2 places using google map api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google map API and Phonegap. I am trying to create an app which will show the possible routes between the origin and destiny.

So is it possible to get multiple routes with direction using Google map API.

Is there any other API apart from Google which will provide me the multiple route. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [DirectionsRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest) query has a boolean parameter `provideRouteAlternatives` that returns alternate routes in the [DirectionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult) object.

Here is the documentation on working with the [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions):